# Form Data to get a particular output from urlencode

Tags: urlencode, google-forms

What should be the dictionary form_data

Desired Output from python code >> data = parse.urlencode(form_data).encode():

"entry.330812148_sentinel=&entry.330812148=Test1&entry.330812148=Test2&entry.330812148=Test3&entry.330812148=Test4"

I tried various dictionary structures including ones with None, [] and dictionary within dictionary but I am unable to get this output

form_data = {'entry.330812148_sentinel':None,
            'entry.330812148':'Test1',
            'entry.330812148':'Test2',
            'entry.330812148':'Test3',
            'entry.330812148':'Test4'}

from urllib import request, parse
data = parse.urlencode(form_data).encode()
print("Printing Parsed Form Data........")

"entry.330812148_sentinel=&entry.330812148=Test1&entry.330812148=Test2&entry.330812148=Test3&entry.330812148=Test4"

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse_qs from urllib.parse to return the python data structure

```
import urllib.parse
>>> s = 'entry.330812148_sentinel=&entry.330812148=Test1&entry.330812148=Test2&entry.330812148=Test3&entry.330812148=Test4'

>>> d1 = urllib.parse.parse_qs(s)
>>> d1
   {b'entry.330812148': [b'Test1', b'Test2', b'Test3', b'Test4']}
```